# What is the meaning of $\chi$ in this expression? Possibly the Legendre chi function?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, dirichlet-series

I was reading through the proof of the existence of the Gibbs phenomenon for the ramp function
$$
f(t) = \frac{\pi}{2} \mathrm{sgn}(t) - \frac{t}{2}
$$
 at $t=0$, where the author states the following without any explanation as to where the $\chi$-function comes from:
$$
\ldots
= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{n}} \sin(nt)\left( \frac{ \cos\left( \frac{ t }{ 2 }\right) }{ 2\sin \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) } - \frac{ 1 }{ t } \right)\,\mathrm{d}t
= \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(nt)\left( \frac{ \cos\left( \frac{ t }{ 2 }\right) }{ 2\sin \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) } - \frac{ 1 }{ t } \right) \chi_{[0,x_n]}(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,,
$$
where $x_n = \frac{\pi}{n}$.
The author then goes on to define the function $g$ as follows:
$$
g = \left( \frac{ \cos\left( \frac{ t }{ 2 }\right) }{ 2\sin \left( \frac{t}{2} \right) } - \frac{ 1 }{ t } \right) \chi_{[0,x_n]}(t)
$$
and develop a continuous extension
$$
G_n =
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&g_n(t) &&,\quad -\pi\leq t\leq \pi,\quad t\neq 0\\
&0 &&,\quad t=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
for it in order to use the ML-theorem from complex analysis to prove the convergence of the integral.

My question is, what is the meaning of $\chi_{[0,x_n]}(t)$ in this context? Some Googling resulted in me discovering the [Legendre chi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function),
but in its case the sub-index $\nu$ is usually a natural number, whereas here it seems to be an interval on the real line.

I'm baffled by this to say the least. I should say this is for my bachelor's thesis, so I would also appreciate any suggestions concerning literature on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is often (as it is here) used to denote the indicator function, specifically $\chi_A(x)$ is set to $1$ if $x\in A,$ and $0$ otherwise.

In your case, the integration is effectively restricted to the interval $[0,x_n].$